# Calculating slope and aspect from DTM lidar elevation data in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dem, elevation, slope, aspect

I have an ASCII 2m lidar DTM file which I converted into a raster in ArcGIS with the From ASCII to Raster tool. From this DTM file I would like to calculate the slope and aspect. I have used the spatial analyst -> surface toolbox for this. The DTM has a BNG projection and all values are calculated in degrees. I followed several different tutorials and they all show a same result, a 'equal and smooth' raster with slope or aspect values ([ArcGIS](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/how-slope-works.htm) and [GIScourse](http://giscourse.com/index.php/blog-giscourse/122-how-to-create-a-slope-map-from-a-digital-terrain-model-in-arcgis-2)).

However, when I try to do this for my DTM raster, I get both 'smooth' parts (left side of pictures) but also what seems like contour lines (right side of pictures). It seems like they follow the lines of the DTM where values change, not really changes in slope etc.

Had anybody had the same problem and/or can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: If the east side of your area has a stair-like relief (likke paddy fields), your result seem normal

Comment: @GISGe Unfortunately, the east side does not have this stair-like relief, that is the problem.

Comment: Then you should maybe check the quality of your DTM and how the conversion from lidar was made, because the stairs seem to be present in your data. Using a category-based symbology instead of this smooth gradient will make the pattern more visible.

Comment: When converting to raster specify cell type as FLOAT, not INTEGER.

Comment: Did you try to import your lidar data as vector points and create a DTM from it and then run aspect/slope?

Comment: Thanks all for the comments! It was indeed by importing it as an INTEGER instead of FLOAT. Thank you very much for the tips!